# Button pressed to next "storyboard" Programmatically designing UI in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
let signupButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
signupButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
signupButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "signupButton"), forState: .Normal)
signupButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
signupButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)
signupButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("SIGN UP", comment: ""), forState: .Normal)

self.view.addSubview(signupButton)
// width constraint
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[SignupButton(==149)]", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["SignupButton": signupButton]))

// height constraint
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[SignupButton(==60)]", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["SignupButton": signupButton]))

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-464.5-[signupButton]-142.5-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["signupButton": signupButton]))
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-196-[signupButton]-30-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["signupButton": signupButton]))
```

When this button is pressed, I need it to essentially push to another ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You must write the button action using the code

```
signupButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

then create a function named pressed

```
func pressed (sender:UIButton!) {

//write the code for changing view controller

}
```

Comment: As an additional suggestion, given the question title, I'd suggest @vkrishnan23 to investigate `performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?)`

Comment: Yes, but this causes the SIGABRT App Delegate error. Is this is an issue with where I'm declaring the signupButton.addTarget, because it is declared before the subview.

Comment: @MatteoPiombo the issue with that is that I'm designing the UI programmatically, and therefore can't create segues since those are through the storyboard, that can be called using the performSeguewithIdentifier.

Comment: Ups, so you do not have storyboard and segues at all. You might consider changing your question title, since it might be a little misleading. Anyway @azhar answer holds. In the code you write inside it you'll probably have to  create the new view controller and call `presentViewController...`. This depends on your app's logic.